# Запрет пингования VDS

Tags: debian, ping

Как запретить пингование VDS-сервера, но при этом, чтобы можно было добавить IP-адреса, которым разрешено пинговать?

Comment: например http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-9-allow-icmp-ping.html  вообще гугл дает кучу готовых ответов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

полностью заблокировать приём icmp-пакетов:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

заблокировать только приём icmp-пакетов типа *echo-request*:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

---

а) для разрешения приёма таких пакетов от определённого ip-адреса можно добавить **перед** этим правилом *netfilter*-а разрешающее правило:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s ip-адрес -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

можно либо добавлять по одному правилу для каждого ip-адреса, либо:

1. перечислить несколько через запятую: `-s ip-адрес,ip-адрес,...`
2. указать маску: `-s ip-адрес/маска` (по умолчанию подразумевается маска 32 бита)
3. если доступен модуль *iprange*, указать диапазон ip-адресов: `-m iprange --src-range 1.1.1.1-1.1.1.10`

б) для разрешения приёма таких пакетов от определённого ip-адреса можно в то же самое правило добавить **отрицание** (с помощью `!`):

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT ! -s ip-адрес -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

в этом случае можно применить те же способы для указания нескольких ip-адресов, что и описаны выше.